# intersection of two step functions

Tags: r, set, intersection

I trying to determine the point (x,y) where two functions intersect. The functions are the step interpolation between sets of points. One function is weakly increasing (`v1`) and the other weakly decreasing (`v2`). I'm coding in R, but a general algorithm is also ok.

If it helps, this is to determine market equilibrium with sets of supply and demand points.

The length of the two vectors is different and their x's and y's will not be the same.

Some example data:

```
set.seed(4)

v1 = data.frame( y = cumsum( runif(10) ) ,
                 x = cumsum( runif(10) ) )
v2 = data.frame( y = 5-cumsum( runif(8) )  ,
                 x = cumsum( runif(8) ) )

plot(y=0,x=0,type="n",xlim=c(0,5),ylim=c(0,5),xlab="x",ylab="y")

lines( y=v1$y , x=v1$x , type="S" , col="blue" )
lines( y=v1$y , x=v1$x , type="p" , col="blue" )

lines( y=v2$y , x=v2$x , type="s" , col="red" )
lines( y=v2$y , x=v2$x , type="p" , col="red" )
```

In this example, the intersection is at (x=2.7275363 , y=2.510405), where the `x` is from `v2` and `y` is from `v1`.

Thanks

Comment: Actually the exact point of intersection seem to to be at (x=2.727536
, y=2.239863). You can confirm what you expect the answer to be?

Comment: I've left my computer at work so can't confirm, but it is likely I made a mistake with the y number. So, take it as being `y=2.239863`. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another think about the problem. A key issue is that I need to find the intersection within an optimisation routine, so it has to be fast. So, I came up with the following (included here in case others have to same problem in the future). It is a modified Bentley-Ottmann algorithm.

```
# create some data
supply = data.frame( p =                    cumsum( runif(1000) ) ,
                     q =                    cumsum( runif(1000) ) )
demand = data.frame( p = tail(supply,1)$p - cumsum( runif(1000) )  ,
                     q =                    cumsum( runif(1000) ) )

# create tables that identify coordinates of horizontal and vertical lines 
demand.h = cbind( p       = head(demand,-1)$p , 
                  q.lower = head(demand,-1)$q , 
                  q.upper = tail(demand,-1)$q )

supply.v = cbind( q       = head(supply,-1)$q ,
                  p.lower = head(supply,-1)$p ,
                  p.upper = tail(supply,-1)$p )

demand.v = cbind( q       = tail(demand,-1)$q ,
                  p.lower = tail(demand,-1)$p ,
                  p.upper = head(demand,-1)$p )

supply.h = cbind( p       = tail(supply,-1)$p ,
                  q.lower = head(supply,-1)$q ,
                  q.upper = tail(supply,-1)$q )

# define a function
find.intersection = function( f.A , f.B ){
  f.result = any( f.B[,2]<=f.A[1]  & f.B[,3]>=f.A[1]  & 
                  f.A[2] <=f.B[,1] & f.A[3] >=f.B[,1] )
  return( f.result )
}

# find the intersection
intersection.h = c( demand.h[ apply( demand.h , 
                                     MARGIN=1 , 
                                     FUN=find.intersection , 
                                     supply.v ) , 1 ] ,
                    supply.v[ apply( supply.v , 
                                     MARGIN=1 , 
                                     FUN=find.intersection , 
                                     demand.h ) , 1 ] )

intersection.v = c( supply.h[ apply( supply.h , 
                                     MARGIN=1 , 
                                     FUN=find.intersection , 
                                     demand.v ) , 1 ] ,
                    demand.v[ apply( demand.v , 
                                     MARGIN=1 , 
                                     FUN=find.intersection , 
                                     supply.h ) , 1 ] )

intersection = c( intersection.h , intersection.v )

# (optional) if you want to print the graph and intersection
plot(y=0,x=0,type="n",
     xlim=c(intersection[2]-1,intersection[2]+1),
     ylim=c(intersection[1]-1,intersection[1]+1),
     xlab="q",ylab="p")

lines( y=supply$p , x=supply$q , type="S" , col="black" )
lines( y=supply$p , x=supply$q , type="p" , col="black" )

lines( y=demand$p , x=demand$q , type="s" , col="black" )
lines( y=demand$p , x=demand$q , type="p" , col="black" )

points(intersection[2],intersection[1], pch=20, col="red")
abline( v=intersection[2], h=intersection[1], lty=2 , col="red")
```

Answer (score 2):

As I was facing the same issue, but was dependent on speed. I used the wonderful `Rcpp` to speed the code up.

If anybody is interested, this is what I did:

```r
library(dplyr)   # for data manipulation only, not used for the algorithm!
library(ggplot2) # for data graphing only, not used for the algorithm!

# Load (i.e., Source the Cpp function)
Rcpp::sourceCpp("find_optimum.cpp")

# small helper function that plots the supply and demand as a step-function
plot_supply_demand <- function(supply, demand) {
  supply_df <- supply %>% 
    bind_rows(data_frame(p = -Inf, q = 0)) %>% 
    arrange(p) %>% 
    mutate(agg_q = cumsum(q), side = "supply") %>% 
    bind_rows(data_frame(p = Inf, q = 0, agg_q = sum(supply$q), side = "supply"))

  demand_df <- demand %>% 
    bind_rows(data_frame(p = Inf, q = 0)) %>% 
    arrange(desc(p)) %>% 
    mutate(agg_q = cumsum(q), side = "demand") %>% 
    bind_rows(data_frame(p = -Inf, q = 0, agg_q = sum(demand$q), side = "demand"))

  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = p, y = agg_q, color = side)) + 
    geom_step(data = demand_df, direction = "vh") +
    geom_step(data = supply_df)
}

# create two data_frames containing the disaggregated data (i.e., orders)
# by graphing the data, or by calculating it by hand we see the optimum at (10, 2)
supply_small = data_frame(p = c(8, 10),
                    q = c(1, 2))

demand_small = data_frame(p = c(12, 10, 8),
                    q = c(1, 1, 1))

plot_supply_demand(supply_small, demand_small) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = 10, y = 2), color = "red", size = 5)
```

[image]

```r
find_optimum(supply_small$p, supply_small$q, demand_small$p, demand_small$q)
#> $price
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> $quantity
#> [1] 2
```

## Larger example

```r
set.seed(12345678)
demand <- data_frame(p = runif(100, 80, 200), q = rnorm(100, 10, 2))
supply <- data_frame(p = runif(100, 0, 120), q = rnorm(100, 10, 2))

opt <- find_optimum(supply$p, supply$q, demand$p, demand$q)
opt
#> $price
#> [1] 102.5982
#> 
#> $quantity
#> [1] 841.8772


plot_supply_demand(supply, demand) +
  geom_point(aes(x = opt$price, y = opt$quantity), color = "red", size = 2)
```

[image]

To zoom in a bit on the optimum, we can use the following

```r
plot_supply_demand(supply, demand) +
  geom_point(aes(x = opt$price, y = opt$quantity), color = "red", size = 2) +
  xlim(opt$price + c(-10, 10)) + ylim(opt$quantity + c(-50, 50))
#> Warning: Removed 92 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
#> Warning: Removed 93 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-10-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

## Rcpp Function

And last but not least, the `C++` function in `find_optimum.cpp` that does the heavy lifting:

```r
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <map>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List find_optimum(Rcpp::NumericVector price_supply,
                        Rcpp::NumericVector quant_supply,
                        Rcpp::NumericVector price_demand,
                        Rcpp::NumericVector quant_demand) {

  std::map<double, double> supply;
  std::map<double, double> demand;

  // fill the maps
  for (int i = 0; i < price_supply.size(); ++i) {
    supply[price_supply[i]] += quant_supply[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < price_demand.size(); ++i) {
    demand[price_demand[i]] += quant_demand[i];
  }

  if (supply.empty() || demand.empty()) 
    return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("price") = 0, Rcpp::Named("quantity") = 0);

  auto sIt = supply.begin(), nextS = std::next(sIt, 1);
  const auto endS = supply.end();
  auto dIt = demand.rbegin(), nextD = std::next(dIt, 1);
  const auto endD = demand.rend();

  // quantity and prices at either side
  double pS = sIt->first, pD = dIt->first;
  double qS = 0, qD = 0;

  // next prices
  double nextPS = nextS->first, nextPD = nextD->first;
  if (pD < pS) 
    return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("price") = 0, Rcpp::Named("quantity") = 0);

  // add the best price from each side!
  qS += sIt->second;
  qD += dIt->second;

  while (pS < pD) {
    if (nextS == endS && nextD == endD) {
      pD = qD < qS ? pS : pD;
      break;
    }

    while (qS <= qD && sIt != endS && nextS->first <= pD) {
      ++sIt;
      ++nextS;
      pS = sIt->first;
      qS += sIt->second;
    }
    if (sIt == endS) break;

    if (nextD->first < pS) {
      pD = qD < qS ? pS : pD;
      break;
    }

    while (qD < qS && dIt != endD && nextD->first >= pS) {
      ++dIt;
      ++nextD;
      pD = dIt->first;
      qD += dIt->second;
    }
    if (dIt == endD) break;
  }

  double price = pD;
  double vol = qS < qD ? qS : qD;

  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("price") = price, 
                            Rcpp::Named("quantity") = vol);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're drawing your step lines differently in each case:  v1 you change the vertical first, and then the horizontal (up and across), whereas for v2 you reverse the order (across then down).  Assuming this is correct, then your intersection point will be at or immediately after a point in v1 where the next point along the axis is a v1 with a lower y coordinate.  We can find that by doing:

```
v1$v <- 1
v2$v <- 2
v3 <- rbind(v1,v2)
v3 <- v3[order(v3$x),]
v3$diff <- c( diff(v3$y),0)
ind <- which(v3$diff < 0 & v3$v ==1)[1]
```

There are now two distinct cases - the intersection could be on the horizontal or vertical arm following this point from v1.  It will be the former if the immediately preceeding v2 is higher than the v1 after our found one; otherwise it will be in the horizontal arm.  This is clear if you draw it out - I'll try and attach an image if you don't see this.

```
previousV2 <- tail(which(v3$v[1:ind]==2),1)
nextV1 <- which(v3$v[-(1:ind)]==1)[1] + ind
if (v3$y[previousV2] > v3$y[nextV1]) {
  x <- v3$x[ind+1]
  y <- v3$y[nextV1]
} else {
  x <- v3$x[ind]
  y <- v3$y[previousV2]
}
```

Worryingly, this doesn't agree with your (x=2.7275363 , y=2.510405) answer, but when I plot it, mine appears on the intersection.  So either: I haven't understood what you want; you've miscalculated; or there's a different scheme regarding the order of horizontal and vertical components.  The above code should be adaptable to different schemes.

Comment: Try running your method with `set.seed(5)` and `set.seed(7)`. I added `abline(v=x, lty=2); abline(h=y, lty=2)` to the end to see the results. It seems like things can get tricky. Must have to do with how R decides to draw the lines. If the point is to find the intersection of the lines that R draws, that's one thing; but maybe that's not really the answer the OP is after. Hopefully he can clarify.

Comment: Hmmm, good catch.  There should be some logic that catches this behaviour. I think we need an `ind2 <- which(v3$diff > 0 & v3$v==2)` and see which of the ind's occurs first- been a long week, and can't quickly see if this conditional needs it's own logic shown in my second chunk of code or not, but hopefully it should provide a basis  for the OP

Comment: Regarding how R draws the lines, it depends on the case of the `type="s/S"` parameter whether it's horizontal or vertical first - I assumed this was a deliberate distinction in the question, but maybe not.

Comment: I missed the "s/S" distinction so likely that was intentional. It seems so simple by eye, but is a bit tricker by code. But you did provide a cleaner start than I had.

Comment: Yes, the s/S distinction was deliberate.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have something that works but it's a lot more complicated than i was expecting.

First, let me define a helper function

```
between <- function(x, a, b) {
    if(missing(b)) {
        if(length(a)==2) {
          a<-t(a)
       }
    } else {
        a <- unname(cbind(a,b))
    }
    a<-t(apply(a,1,sort))
    a[,1] <= x & x <= a[,2]
}
```

this just helps to check if a number is between two others. Now I will `embed` the two data.frames to make sets of consecutive point pairs, then i check each possible combination for segments that overlap in just the right way. (It's important that `v1` here is the "S" and `v2` is the `s`.)

```
sa<-embed(as.matrix(v1[,c("x","y")]),2)
sz<-embed(as.matrix(v2[,c("x","y")]),2)
xx<-outer(1:nrow(sa), 1:nrow(sz), function(a,z)
    (between(sa[a,2], sz[z,c(2,4)]) & between(sz[z,1], sa[a,c(1,3)])) *1 
     + (between(sz[z,4], sa[a,c(2,4)]) & between(sa[a,3], sz[z,c(1,3)]))*2
)
```

Now `xx` contains the matching set of points, I just need to extract the correct coordinates depending on which type of intersection occurred.

```
i <- which(xx!=0, arr.ind=T)
int.pt <- if(nrow(i)>0 && ncol(i)==2) {
    if(xx[i]==1) {
       c(sz[i[2],1], sa[i[1],2])
    } else if (xx[i]==2) {
       c(sa[i[1],3], sz[i[2],4])
    }
} else {
   c(NA,NA)
}
#optionally plot intersection
#if (all(!is.na(int.pt))) {
#    points(int.pt[1],int.pt[2], pch=20, col="black")
#    abline(v=int.pt[1], h=int.pt[2], lty=2)
#}
```

Perhaps there is a better way, but at least you have another method that seems to work to compare answers with.

[image: sample intersection detection]

Comment: Thanks! This approach works well. I'll play around with it and post my solution if I can speed it up.